# PHP and JQuery: value not updating

Tags: php, jquery

Couple questions:

1) I'm trying to have a new random value updated each time a button is pressed. When the button is clicked, a value is generated once... but is not random. So I'm not sure if the function is being called again on click because a new value isn't generated.

2) Can I include the php code within the same file as the jquery when using a server call such as $.get() and call it as a function within that same file?

The reason is, I don't want to have to keep creating new php script files, and would rather throw the code in the same file as the calling jquery.

Meaning...

Instead of `$.get("../scripts/NameGenerator2.php",`

I do this: `$.get("a php function within this same file",`

**JQuery:**

```
<?php 
   if ($imgid == 1) {
?>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

<button id="generateButton">Generate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#generateButton").click(function(e) {
            //alert("called");
           $.get("../scripts/NameGenerator2.php", 
                function(returned_data) {
                    $("#generated").html(returned_data);
                }
            ).error(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log("error in $.get")
            });
        });
    });
</script>       
<?php } ?>
<br /><span id="generated"></span><br />
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$adj = array("Happy", "Great", "Mandarin", "New", "Golden", "Ming's");
$noun = array("Dragon", "Sea", "Wok", "Fortune", "Rice", "Empire");
$place = array("Garden", "China", "Village", "Palace", "Kitchen", "Mountain");


$x = rand(0, count($adj)-1);
$y = rand(0, count($noun)-1);
$z = rand(0, count($place)-1);

echo '<p>' . $adj[$x] . " " . $noun[$y] . " " . $place[$z] . '</p>';

?>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Updated: Only error I seem to be getting is "Object Expected" in my "myJquery.js" file, which is not the file I'm working in, and doesn't seem connected.

[image]

When I add in document ready to my function, the button onclick() call seems to break.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer, but all of your jQuery functions need to be in your document ready handler. there are no functions in your document ready handler.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I thought that handler was optional, or you could multiple instances of it.

Comment: It is only optional if the jQuery is near the bottom of the page to insure that the DOM elements exist before the jQuery code is called. You can have multiple instances but you do not.

Comment: @JayBlanchard also, adding that handler seems to break my button onclick="generate()" call, saying "Object Expected". see above

Comment: I don't know how it could break it but you shouldn't use inline javascript if you can do it more cleanly. Since you're using jQuery you can perform all of this without inline javascript. I am concerned that we are not seeing all of your code and markup in the proper context. Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im developing locally. But the live site is www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com. It doesn't have this update, but you can picture this code in the live site code.

Comment: Picture it? No. In order to troubleshoot the issues we have to be able to see the code in question, check for errors and determine what to do to make things work as you expect them to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21405/discussion-between-growler-and-jay-blanchard)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll try to get something on the live site when I'm home. But, I don't think there's an issue with the javascript. Am I right in thinking that each time I press the "Generate" button that it should send a new request to the NameGenerator2.php file, and so the random functions should generate new values, right? Maybe it's my php file that's incorrect.

Comment: You would be correct - but we want to check everything.

Comment: @JayBlanchard WOW... It works in FireFox but not IE 8 (where I've been testing it). What the heck is wrong with Internet Explorer?! Btw, is there any way to layer the button over an image? I'd like to display the button within a comic, not above or below it.

Comment: Yes, you can position the button using CSS. Take out your console.log statements (IE chokes on these) and it should work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That did not fix it for IE

Comment: Is IE giving you any errors at all? Have you looked at the developer console to see what is happening?

Comment: @JayBlanchard None that seem to be helpful. Also, I've asked a question connected to this one. Would you be able to help on it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960562/php-updating-url-pushstate-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a PHP function but you can load the page and get a specific div -

```
$('#generated').load('../scripts/NameGenerator2.php #pagePart');
```

You echo out PHP with the proper id's in place, for instance -

```
echo '<p id="pagePart">' . $adj[$x] . " " . $noun[$x] . " " . $place[$x] . '</p>';
```

Without using any inline JavaScript this is what your jQuery code might look like -

```
<button id="generate">Generate</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#generate').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#generated').load('../scripts/NameGenerator2.php #pagePart');
    });
});
```

Based on your update you need to move all of your jQuery functions into the document ready function.

Answer (score 3):

You can call a .php-file with jQuery. But the file should be reachable with your browser and should return qualified data.

With [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you can define the expected data-type. It can be xml, json, script, or html.
If you want to use json (my favourite) the use the php-function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) to generate the output.

If you want to use the same file, create a GET-Parameter e.g. ?ajax=1. With your AJAX-request you call the file and append the GET-Parameter. And in your .php-File you can then switch between an normal call and an ajax call which returns an other output.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
        // header("Content-type: application/json");
        // $data = array(some_data);
        // echo json_encode($data);
        echo 'AJAX-call-output';
    } else {
?>
        <!-- [...] -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function generate() {     
               $.get("../scripts/NameGenerator2.php",
                    { ajax: 1 },  // GET-Parameter
                    function(returned_data) {
                        //alert("test");
                        $("#generated").html(returned_data);
                    }
                    //, "json"
                );
            }
        </script>
        <!-- [...] -->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I get the idea of what you're saying. Can you perhaps provide a quick example?